# Jpa not saving or updating table during multiple query

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have 4 update queries and I am running them in the same method. I want the table to be updated on every update query but the table is getting updated after all 4 queries are executed. 
Usecase:
I am continuously fetching the AWS EMR cluster details and I want to update the dB table as soon as I get a changed status. For this I have created a table with 5 columns and want to update the column as soon as I get the changed status. I have 4 update queries in my custom repository. Now my table is getting updated but only after all the 4 queries are executed but I want the table to be updated after each update query

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. A code example here would be really useful. Also specify how you are checking the database?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are executing all queries from a single transaction, and when that transaction is committed, you are able to see the result.

Try executing each query in separate transactions.

Check where you are using the `@Transactional` annotation.

Note: Even you are not seeing update in DB after all 4 queries, the update of the first query will be visible to second query from transaction context.

Assumption: I am assuming you are checking into DB from outside an application (from db client).

Comment: @Transactional
 @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
 @Query("update ProgressBarInfo pb set clusterInitialized=:clusterInitializedStatus where executionId=:executionId")
 public int updateClusterInitializedStatus(@Param("executionId") long executionId, @Param("clusterInitializedStatus") String clusterInitializedStatus);

I am using 3 more queries like this in a same method in service impl layer

Comment: @ApoorvAsthana please update your question instead of trying to squeeze code into comments.